# Metadata map for importing CSV data into IPTC XMP images using Bridge

Tags: csv, metadata, xmp, iptc

Let's say I have 100 scanned Tif files.  I also have a CSV of the metadata for those 100 Tif files.  Each file is named with its unique identifier, which is also column 1 of the csv.

First:  How do I find a map that tells me what columns should be named what, in order to stay within the IPTC standard using XMP? (I've googled for most of the day and have found nothing)

Second:  How can I merge the metadata in the CSV to each corresponding image?

I'm basically creating a spreadsheet with all 50,000 images in an archival collection, and plan to use the CSV to create the metadata for the images once they're scanned.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To know where to put your metadata, I'd suggest looking at the [IPTC Photo Metadata Standard](https://iptc.org/standards/photo-metadata/iptc-standard/) page. Without knowing more about your data, it's hard for someone else to say what data should go where.

As for embedding your data into your files from a CSV file, I'd suggest [exiftool](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/). Change the header of each column to the name of the TAG to write to and make the first column the path/filename of each file, your command would be as simple as
`exiftool -csv=file.csv /path/to/files`

See [exiftool FAQ #26](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/faq.html#Q26) for more details.